# Range of pdf of $X + Y$ when $(X,Y)$ has pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-y}1_{0<x<y}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

The joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is

$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =  e^{-y} $  for $ 0 < x < y $.

I need to find the PDF for $Z = X + Y$. To do this to take the integral of  $ f_{X,Y}(z-y,x) $ over the range of $Z$. The solution is telling me the range is $z/2 < y < z $ , and supposedly you get this from $ 0 < z-y < y $ , but to me this makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

$0 <z-y<y$ implies that $z <2y$ so $y >\frac z 2$. Also $0<z-y$ implies that $y<z$ so we get $\frac z 2 <y<z$. Conversely, $\frac z 2 <y<z$ gives $0<z-y <y$ so these two sets of inequalities are equivalent.

How do we get $0<z-y<y$?  We get this directly from the definition of $f_{x,y}$. Just verify that if these inequalities are not satisfied then $f_{x,y}(z-y,x)=0$

Comment: oh i dont know how i didnt see that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

- $z=x+y$ so $x=y-z$
- $0 \lt x \lt y$ so $0 \lt z-y \lt y$
- Adding $y$ throughout $0 \lt z-y \lt y$ gives  $y \lt z \lt 2y$ and so $2y \lt 2z$
- Dividing by (positive) $2$ throughout $z \lt 2y \lt 2z$ gives $\frac{z}{2} \lt y \lt z$